# CSS style specific div without id

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am making an ebay storefront and need to style an element on the page which I have no ability to edit the html of.

The html is something like this

```
<td id="blah">
  <div>
    <div>....

    </div>
  </div>
  <div>....

  </div>
</td>
```

I need to add a margin to both the div's

..but not the children divs of those divs

the css I tried was `#blah div {margin:5px;}` but of course that effected the child divs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [`>` "immediate child"](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_child.html) selector:

```
#blah > div {margin:5px;}
```

but it's [not supported by IE6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), which sadly still is a consideration for many audiences.

It's preferable to add a class to the box you want to style:

```
<td id="blah">
  <div class="box">
    <div>....
```

and specify that:

```
#blah div.box {margin:5px;}
```

Comment: was just about to post that, demo'd in Chrome and it doesn't work?

Comment: the immediate child selector, not the new class (OP can't add a class) see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/39LnU/1/

Comment: @Myles that's because you're using a `<td>` out of a table context. It works when you change it to a div: http://jsfiddle.net/39LnU/3/ however, font size is one of the properties that are inherited to children, so the text isn't accurate :)

Comment: Ah-ha very clever, I didn't know CSS wouldn't allow such things :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use what you have, just add another selector to override the children:

```
#blah div 
{
    margin:5px;
}

#blah div div
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Give that a go :)

Comment: Thanks... unfortunately some of the child divs had margins of their own.

Answer (score 0):

You need the child, not descendant selector:

```
#blah > div
```